# Cmake Custom Target not selected for configuration

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I have cmake a custom command and custom target which runs doxygen to generate documentation from the header files.

However Visual Studio doesn't build this target when the build is started from command line. It says "Project not selected to build for this solution configuration". Is there a way make sure this target is selected for the release (or debug) configuration in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the [add_dependencies](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3aadd_dependencies) command.

After you have defined they doxygen target and an executable or library target, write something like

```
add_dependencies( my_executable my_custom_doxygen_target )
```

This will force the doxygen target to be built every time your executable is.

It may also be possible to make it work by turning off the `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` property on your doxygen target. I expected to see `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` mentioned in the description of `add_custom_target`, but didn't - so it might be different than I remember.